# how to display dropdown list items on the right side?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML code (drop down) and for some reasons i want to display items on the right side without using a direction on select tag directly.

It works on fire fox but do not works on IE(ver 11).

I used these codes and css but it does not work

```
<select name="SelectedGroup" style="text-align:right" id="groups" >
    <option  value="">Select one</option>
    <option style="text-align:right; " value="1">abcd#1</option>
    <option style="text-align:right; direction:rtl;" value="2">abcd#2</option>
    <option value="3">abcd#3</option>
    <option value="4">abcd#4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in IE11 using direction. try this

```
<select name="SelectedGroup" dir="rtl" id="groups" >
    <option  value="">Select one</option>
    <option value="1">abcd#1</option>
    <option value="2">abcd#2</option>
    <option value="3">abcd#3</option>
    <option value="4">abcd#4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i don't want to use direction on select tag,directly